# How can I cast a Pandas string column to the new nullable Int64 type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, types

I am trying to cast a string column in a Pandas DataFrame into numeric columns.

I use the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': ['1', '2'], 'col2': ['5', str(np.nan)], 'col3': [99, str(pd.NA)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

> ```
>   col1 col2  col3
> 0    1    5    99
> 1    2  nan  <NA>
> ```

Now, when I cast `col1` from to `int`, and `col2` to `float`, it works fine:

```
print(df.col1.astype(int))
print(df.col2.astype(float))
```

> ```
> 0    1
> 1    2
> Name: col1, dtype: int64
> 0    5.0
> 1    NaN
> Name: col2, dtype: float64
> ```

But when I try to cast `col3` from `str` to `Int64` I get the following error:

```
df.col3.astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
```

> `TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype`

Is this intended?

How can I overcome this limitation?

**EDIT:** I edited the example data to make the intention clearer.

Comment: Why cast to string but not directly `df.col3.astype('Int64')`?

Comment: from sample data `df['col3'].dtype` already is `Int64Dtype()` ..? Not a string

Comment: Sorry, it might have been unclear, but I set the type just for mocking this sample data. Think of it as string columns containing numerical data.

Comment: Try `.round()` as an intermediate step.

Comment: @dremok Can you change the example data so that it’s less confusing?

Comment: Sure, I will try to clarify further

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**:

Your sample data has column `col3` as having an integer `99` and a string representation of `pd.NA`, but your question title asking about string column. So, just in case you meant that `col3` has a string `'99'` and a string representation of `pd.NA` such as

```
In [124]: s1 = pd.Series(['99', str(pd.NA)])

In [125]: s1
Out[125]:
0      99
1    <NA>
dtype: object

In [126]: s1.map(type)
Out[126]:
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
dtype: object
```

In this case, pandas doesn't allow using `astype` to direct convert it to `Int64`. You need to use `pd.to_numeric` with `'coerce'` and cast to `Int64`

```
In [130]: s = pd.to_numeric(s1, errors='coerce').astype('Int64')

In [131]: s
Out[131]:
0      99
1    <NA>
dtype: Int64

In [132]: s.map(type)
Out[132]:
0                            <class 'int'>
1    <class 'pandas._libs.missing.NAType'>
dtype: object
```

---

**Original**:

In pandas 1.0.0+, `pd.NA` is introduced to represent missing values for the nullable integer and boolean data types and the new string data type. When you call `str` on `pd.NA` (i.e. you call `str(pd.NA)` in dataframe constructor for `col3`), it returns the its string representation. Its string representation is string `<NA>`.

```
In [84]: pd.NA.__str__()
Out[84]: '<NA>'
```

It is the same as you call `str` on `np.nan`, its string representation is string `nan`.

```
In [86]: np.nan.__str__()
Out[86]: 'nan'
```

Therefore, `col3` actually has **NO** `pd.NA`. It just contains an integer `99` and a string representation of `pd.NA` (i.e. it is just a plain string `<NA>`). You want to cast string `<NA>` to the nullable integer type `Int64` (an alias of `pd.Int64Dtype()`), so it errors out.

**The solution**:

You need to replace this plain string `<NA>` to the truly `pd.NA` and cast to `Int64`

```
s = df.col3.replace('<NA>', pd.NA).astype('Int64')

Out[57]:
0      99
1    <NA>
Name: col3, dtype: Int64
```

---

**Detail:**

The `<NA>` in `col3` is clearly just a plain string

```
In [64]: df.loc[1, 'col3']
Out[64]: '<NA>'

In [65]: type(df.loc[1, 'col3'])
Out[65]: str
```

After replacing it with `pd.NA` and cast to `Int64`, it is the truly `pd.NA`

```
In [66]: s = df.col3.replace('<NA>', pd.NA).astype('Int64')

In [68]: s[1]
Out[68]: <NA>

In [69]: type(s[1])
Out[69]: pandas._libs.missing.NAType
```

Comment: Isn't converting to float first kind of problematic? `float64` can only represent a limited subset of integers representable by `int64`. So in some edge cases this method will yield wrong results which could cause errors that are very hard to detect.

Answer (score 2):

`pandas` DataFrame comes with a lot of helpful attributes. When working with the numeric data types, utils like `pandas.to_numeric` stands-out as it provides, with a lot of flexibility with simple syntax.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d  = {'col1': ['1', '2'], 'col2': ['5', str(np.nan)], 'col3': [99, str(pd.NA)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

### 1. Basic Syntax

`to_numeric` expects an `1-d array`, `tuple` or `Series`

```py
print(pd.Series(df['col1']))
# 0    1
# 1    2
# Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

### 2. Error Control

When working with arbitary data, writing reliable scripts involving data type conversion, the required error handling can be repetative and this is provided by `to_numeric`

```py
# Looking at data
print(df['col3'].to_string())
# 0      99
# 1    <NA>
# Name: col3, dtype: object

# This line creates error
df['col3'].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
```

#### a. Ignoring Errors

This will convert all possible values to `numeric` and any unconvertable values will return the `input`

```py
pd.to_numeric(df['col3'], errors='ignore')
# 0      99
# 1    <NA>
# Name: col3, dtype: object

print(pd.to_numeric([1, 2, 3, 'abc'], errors='ignore'))
# array([1, 2, 3, 'abc'], dtype=object)
```

#### b. Coerce Errors

Convert all possible values to `numeric` and any unconvertable values will be returned as `nan` which is (`numpy.nan`)

```py
pd.to_numeric(df['col3'], errors='coerce')
# 0      99
# 1     NaN
# Name: col3, dtype: object

print(pd.to_numeric([1, 2, 3, 'abc'], errors='coerce'))
# array([1, 2, 3, nan])
```

#### c. Raise Errors

Convert all possible values and `raise` errors if encounter any unconvertable values.

```py
pd.to_numeric(df['col3'], errors='raise')
# ValueError: Unable to parse string "<NA>" at position 1

print(pd.to_numeric([1, 2, 3, 'abc'], errors='raise'))
# ValueError: Unable to parse string "abc" at position 3
```

### 3. Downcast Data Type

It will cast to the smallest data type, as per the rules (*as per documentation*)

> - ‘integer’ or ‘signed’: smallest signed int dtype (min.: np.int8)
> - ‘unsigned’:            smallest unsigned int dtype (min.: np.uint8)
> - ‘float’:               smallest float dtype (min.: np.float32)

If the `requested` type size is larger than the `input` then, no `downcasting` is done.

```py
# With a = ['1', '2.0', '-3', 4]

pd.to_numeric(a, downcast='integer')
# array([ 1,  2, -3,  4], dtype=int8)

pd.to_numeric(a, downcast='float')
# array([ 1.,  2., -3.,  4.], dtype=float32)
```

## For your case you would do

```py
pd.to_numeric(df['col3'], errors='coerce').astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
```

*Note the `errors='coerce'` returns a series with `float` data type. which can be converted using the `astype` dataframe attribute as it is a numeric data type.*

Answer (score 0):

Actually float data types can contains NaN but integer values throw error , if you pandas version is less than v0.24
but from v0.24 can contain NaN so you can try

```
df.col3.astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
```

or instead you can replace NaN's by some specific no and then convert to integer

```
df.col3.fillna(-1).astype('Int64')
```

Comment: I use the new pandas 1.0.1

Comment: Your first suggestion is the same as I tried and does not work.

Comment: Your second suggestion does not work, as the column does not contain any NaNs. It contains string representations of `pd.NA` values.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Object.

```
df['col3']=df['col3'].astype(object)
```